# Installed Mechanize, but Python can't find module

Tags: python, mechanize

I installed mechanize into a directory, using the following:

```
sudo easy_install --always-unzip mechanize
Searching for mechanize
Best match: mechanize 0.2.5
Processing mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg
mechanize 0.2.5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth,
```

But I'm getting this error when I call the script scrape.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scrape.py", line 6, in <module>
from mechanize import Browser
ImportError: No module named mechanize
```

I used this script before upgrading to Mac OSX 10.8 (from 10.6) and messing around with Java Ant, if that helps at all. Here's my path:

```
echo $PATH
    /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/ant/bin
```

Could you tell me how to fix this?

EDIT: I fixed this. Set first lines of .bash_profile in home to

```
# Setting PATH for MacPorts Python
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/opt/local/bin/python2.7:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

and got rid of other versions of Python in .bash_profile in home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. Set first lines of .bash_profile in home to

```
# Setting PATH for MacPorts Python
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/opt/local/bin/python2.7:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

and got rid of other versions of Python in .bash_profile in home directory.